# Draw a bounding box over an image present inside a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, bounding-box

I am JavaScript Beginner and I am working on a small code where I have an image displayed inside a Modal and I am trying to draw a bounding box over the image.

I have tried the following code to draw the bounding box over the image.

Html: ( the code for the modal that shows the image)

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

 <!-- The Close Button -->
 <span class="close">&times;</span>

 <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
 <div id="imagearea" class="imagearea">
 <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
 </div>

</div>
```

Javascript: ( the logic that I tried to draw a bounding box over the image)

```
 initDraw(document.getElementById('imgarea'));

function initDraw(imgarea) {
    var mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0
    };
    function setMousePosition(e) {
        var ev = e || window.event; //Moz || IE
        if (ev.pageX) { //Moz
            mouse.x = ev.pageX + window.pageXOffset;
            mouse.y = ev.pageY + window.pageYOffset;
        } else if (ev.clientX) { //IE
            mouse.x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            mouse.y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
    };

    var element = null;
    imgarea.onmousemove = function (e) {
        setMousePosition(e);
        if (element !== null) {
            element.style.width = Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
            element.style.height = Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
            element.style.left = (mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
            element.style.top = (mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
        }
    }

    imagearea.onmouseup = function (e) {
        if (element !== null) {
            element = null;
            imagearea.style.cursor = "default";
            console.log("finsihed.");
        } }
        imagearea.onmousedown = function (e) {
          if(element==null){
            console.log("begun.");
            mouse.startX = mouse.x;
            mouse.startY = mouse.y;
            element = document.createElement('div');
            element.className = 'rectangle'
            element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
            element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
            imagearea.appendChild(element)
            imagearea.style.cursor = "crosshair";
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }
      }
```

css: (for the bounding box)

```
 .rectangle {
      border: 10px solid red;
      position: absolute;
  }
  .imagearea {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     float: left;
     width: 35%;
     max-width: 700px;
     position: relative;
    }
    #img01{
     position: absolute;
     }
```

The above code displays the image in modal and when I try to draw the bounding box on the image, the cursor changes to crosshair as expected , but I could not see the bounding box when i draw it over the image. Just the cursor changes but the rectangle(bounding box) which I draw over the image is not visible.

Can some one help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. You can't append children to `<img>`.
2. Your calculations are based on the viewport, while border's CSS is relative to the image. There are multiple ways to fix that, the quickest one would be to subtract image's position from your mouse position, like this:

```js
function setMousePosition(e) {
    // your mouse calculations

    const boundaries = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();

    mouse.x -= boundaries.left;
    mouse.y -= boundaries.top;
}
```

Also, make sure you use `setMousePosition()` in your `mousedown` handler.

Comment: I have edited the code above , Now I am able to draw the rectangle box but when i draw the box it always starts from the middle of the image and i am able to drag it to outside of the image. Can you help me to fix it by just drawing inside the image

Comment: You can start from using `mousedown` instead of `click`. You probably want to start drawing when the button is pressed, am I correct?

Comment: Also, if you want to make it easier, you could apply background to your `<div>` instead of placing the image there. Otherwise you will need to have either `<img>` or your drawing element have `position: absolute`, along with the `<div>` having `position: relative` to make it work.

Comment: Yes, i want to start drawing when I make the first mouse click and stop for the second mouse click

Comment: Just a note, wouldn't it be more convenient to make start drawing when user presses the mouse button and finish the drawing when they release it?

Comment: yes, it would be much convenient like you said, But i couldnt figure out how to do it. Can you show me what changes i should make to my code to do that

Comment: Just use `mousedown` and `mouseup` events instead of `click`.

Comment: I have edited the above code, the mousedown works but when I try to draw the box, its difficult to finish it as it stops drawing inbetween. Can you check the code above

Comment: Try adding `e.preventDefault()` in your `mousedown` handler to avoid image drag from the browser.

Comment: I have updated the code, Now I am able to draw the box without dragging the picture. But still I am not able to start draw the box from the top left corner of the image. It always starts drawing from the middle of the image.

Comment: I need to go to bed. Possibly, your coords inside the box are relative to the box and not to the page. If nobody helps you, I will help you tomorrow.